# Socket.io not showing alert

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm developing an app using socket.io. What I want is to send an alert with function $alert. The thing is that when I send the nofification via

```
  socket.on('new notification', function(data){
  $alert({
                title: 'All good!',content:'New notification', container:'#alerts-container',
                placement: 'top', duration:3, type: 'success', show: true});
        socket.emit('notification',$scope.currentUser._id, function(data){

        } )
    })
```

I get the errorr: Uncaught TypeError: $alert is not a function from socket.emit and many others. Is there a solution to show an alert through socket.io?

Many thanks

Comment: `$alert` is not something that exists out of the box. Maybe you mean `alert` without the `$` sign?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27746276/30946 ?

Comment: No Hugo Dozois is de mgcrea.ngStrap.alert directive

Comment: jcollum I also tried and nothing